# How can I prevent Xamarin Forms webview "webpage not available" page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I use XF webview and check the connection status, when the connection is broken, I want to prevent the error page and keep it on that page. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the connection status? Do you mean the internet? What is the "on that page" mean? Do you want to back to the previous page when the connection is broken?

Comment: Yes internet, when the internet connection is lost, I want to be stay on the webview page, I don't want to see the "webpage not available" page.

Comment: I have checked it. Load the "https://www.google.com/" and then disconnect the internet. The page is still keeping. What am i missing?

Comment: After waiting for a minute or two, "webpage not available" page  appears @WendyZang-MSFT

Comment: I loaded the page and then disconnected the internet, after five minutes, the page is still on. Have you do any changes with refresh in a minute or two before the "webpage not available" page appearing?

Comment: No, I didn't any changes, by the way I'm not getting an error while testing on the emulator, but the real device is getting an error.

Comment: I tested on the emulator as well. I would test on real device and feedback ASAP.